# Pass parameters from Cloud functions to Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to pass the filename of the file uploaded on Google Cloud Storage from Cloud Functions to Dataflow so that I can process the uploaded file.

The code that I've written for Cloud Functions is

```
const google = require('googleapis');

exports.goWithTheDataFlow = function(event, callback) {
 const file = event.data;
 if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name) {
     console.log(file.name);
   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

     if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
       authClient = authClient.createScoped([
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
       ]);
     }

     const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });

     dataflow.projects.templates.create({
       projectId: '-------',
       resource: {
           parameters: {
           inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`
         },
         jobName: '-------',
         gcsPath: '-------'
       }
     }, function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
       }
       console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
       callback();
     });

   });
 }
};
```

And the code of my Pipeline looks something like this:

```
public interface FruitOptions extends PipelineOptions {
      @Description("Path of the file to read from")
      @Validation.Required
      ValueProvider<String> getInputFile();
      void setInputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);
  }


//Main Method
FruitOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
      .as(FruitOptions.class);
      Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
```

How to create a template of the above Pipeline code? I've been following the link [TRIGGERING DATAFLOW PIPELINES WITH CLOUD FUNCTIONS](https://shinesolutions.com/2017/03/23/triggering-dataflow-pipelines-with-cloud-functions/) to do this but I get several errors while running the maven commands such as:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/PipelineOp
tions
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.optio
ns.PipelineOptions
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.411 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-29T12:16:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/27M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (d
efault-cli) on project Common: An exception occured while executing the Java cla
ss. com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/PipelineOptions: com.google.cloud.data
flow.sdk.options.PipelineOptions -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

And the command that I ran was:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=Common.StarterPipeline -Dexec.args="--project=******** --stagingLocation=gs://******** --dataflowJobFile=gs://********* --runner=TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner"
```

The POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Common</groupId>
  <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh.snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Repository Hosting</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can somebody please help me with this. And please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hi rish, would you please show the errors you're getting. Also, would you mind please describing your use case? Are you trying to launch pipelines from cloud functions specifically? Have you considered just creating a template pipeline and launching it with the dataflow command line tool?

Comment: Hi @AlexAmato

1)I've updated my post with the errors I was getting. 2)The use case is that I want to process each file using dataflow that comes in a particular bucket. So Cloud function must monitor that bucket and trigger the pipeline(template) as soon as a file comes in and send the name of that file to the pipeline. 3)Yes I was trying to launch the pipeline from Cloud Functions. 4) I did but I want the process to be automated as in the pipeline should kick off as soon as the file comes in.

If you feel any other way is better please let me know of it.

Thank You

Comment: Is it possible to provide more details, can you post your maven pom? Are you able to run your pipeline normally, without launching it as a template? Have you verified that that works yet?

Comment: I tried using Dataflow 2.x i.e. Apache Beam and I was successful in creating the template today. The pipeline code, however, remains the same. So I'm guessing something was missing while working with the previous version. But thank you anyways :)

Comment: Sorry, that we didn't pinpoint the issue, but I'm sure that this pom will be useful to others who may come across the same problem. Thanks for posting it :).

Comment: @rish0097 would you please add your result as an answer? That way others will learn from your problem, and you'll get sweet internet points.