# Pass multiple filenames from Cloud functions to Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions

As stated in my previous **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801081/pass-parameters-from-cloud-functions-to-dataflow)** I was trying to pass a single file's name from Cloud Function to Dataflow. What if I uploaded multiple files at a time in a GCS bucket? Is it possible to have a single Cloud Function capture and send all the filenames by using **event.data**? If not any other way I could get those file names in my Dataflow program?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To run this in a single pipeline you would need to create a custom source that took a list of file names (or a single string that was the concatened file names, etc.) and then use that source with an appropriate runtime PipelineOption.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with this approach is that only the client (presumably) knows how many files there are and when they've all completed upload.  Events sent to Cloud Functions are going to be both at-least-once (meaning you may occasionally get more than one) and have events potentially out of order.  Even if the Cloud Function somehow knew how many files it was expecting, you may find it difficult to guarantee only one Cloud Function triggered Dataflow due to a race condition checking Cloud Storage (e.g. more than one function might "think" they are the last one).  There is no "batch" semantic in Cloud Storage (AFAIK) that would lead to a single function invocation (there IS a batch API, but events are emitted from single "object" changes so even a batch write of N files would result in at-least-N events).

It may be better to have the client manually trigger either a Cloud Function, or Dataflow directly, once all files have been uploaded.  You could trigger a Cloud Function either directly via HTTP, or you could just write a sentinel value to Cloud Storage to trigger a function.

The alternative could be to package up the files into a single upload from the client (e.g tar them), but I'm there may be reasons why this doesn't make sense for your use case.